# How to use import and export with Typescript transpilation?

Tags: typescript

I noticed that **babel** and the **webpack** while transpiling the file they generate a `.JS` main file named `"bundle`" **(if you enter this name as entry point)** ...

But this is very good for **SPA (Single Page Application)** systems, in my case I'm creating a **multi page system** and therefore I do not want to load all the unnecessary `.JS` files and all at once ...

So I'm transpiling the typescript in the hand with the command `"tsc filename.js"`, so far so good .. **The problem is that if I export and import it it returns me the following error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at IndexPage.js: 2
```

**What should I do to make it work?**

**IndexPage.ts**

```
import TypingText from '../animations/TypingText';

class OnloadIndexPage {
    public onloadDOM() {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const animation = new TypingText('mainPhraseText', 'Uma estrutura moderna para comparação de repositórios baseada no GitHub');
            animation.start();
        });
    }
}

const init = new OnloadIndexPage();
init.onloadDOM();
```

**TypingText.ts**

```
export default class TypingText {
    private div  : HTMLElement;
    private text : string;

    public constructor(theDivId: string, theText: string){
        this.div  = document.getElementById(theDivId);
        this.text = theText;
    }

    public start(){
        const char = this.text.split('').reverse();
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (!char.length) {
                return this.stop(timer)
            } else {
                const next = char.pop();
                this.div.innerHTML += next;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    private stop(timer){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

}
```

**When I compile it it looks like this:**
**TypingText.js**

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var TypingText = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TypingText(theDivId, theText) {
        this.div = document.getElementById(theDivId);
        this.text = theText;
    }
    TypingText.prototype.start = function () {
        var _this = this;
        var char = this.text.split('').reverse();
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (!char.length) {
                return _this.stop(timer);
            }
            else {
                var next = char.pop();
                _this.div.innerHTML += next;
            }
        }, 100);
    };
    TypingText.prototype.stop = function (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
    return TypingText;
}());
exports["default"] = TypingText;
```

**IndexPage.js**

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var TypingText_1 = require("../animations/TypingText");
var OnloadIndexPage = /** @class */ (function () {
    function OnloadIndexPage() {
    }
    OnloadIndexPage.prototype.onloadDOM = function () {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var animation = new TypingText_1["default"]('mainPhraseText', 'Uma estrutura moderna para comparação de repositórios baseada no GitHub');
            animation.start();
        });
    };
    return OnloadIndexPage;
}());
var init = new OnloadIndexPage();
init.onloadDOM();
```

Comment: I think the module option in tsconfig is not suited for your usecase. Checking that might solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `webpack`, then you should use a module loader like `SystemJS` which will allow you to load only necessary javascript in your page.

SystemJS can load module in UMD format, you must change your module type to `UMD` in `tsconfig.json` to load through UMD. Although SystemJS can load CommonJS modules but it will require `eval` and you may not be able to apply Content Security Policy to your pages.